Laravel: in-place filtering of an model by dropdown selections
Idea

Via multiple dropdown menus filter the model

Requirements

Page shall not be loaded

Every dropdown selection, filters the model (send queries to DB), as well as adds an query parameter to the URL.

(Not relevant) Also an additional tag button is going to be added which can be deleted.

Example

Tag button, that can be deleted

onRemove, this part is going to be deleted from the query and model will be refreshed.








Coding
HTML
<form id="idSelectTechnology" action="/filter">
    <div class="d-flex mb-2">
        <select id="idSelectType" class="form-select" name="type" aria-label="Default select example">
            <option selected>Type</option>
            <option value="Website">Website</option>
            <option value="Application">Application</option>
            <option value="Design">Design</option>
        </select>
        <select class="form-select" name="technology" aria-label="Default select example">
            <option selected>Technology</option>
            <option value="HTML">HTML</option>
            <option value="CSS">CSS</option>
            <option value="JS">JS</option>
        </select>
        <select class="form-select" name="design" aria-label="Default select example">
            <option selected>Design</option>
            <option value="Figma">Figma</option>
            <option value="Balsamiq">Balsamiq</option>
        </select>
        <select class="form-select" name="feature" aria-label="Default select example">
            <option selected>Feature</option>
            <option value="Responsive">Responsive</option>
            <option value="Database-Connected">Database-Connected</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
</form>

Controller
public function filter(Request $request) {
    dd($request->toArray());
}

Model
use App\Models\portfolioItem;


Issue

Dropdown selections leads to the page being permanently reloaded

Solution
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".form-select").on('change',function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/filter",
            data: jQuery('#idSelectTechnology').serialize(),
            type: "get",
    
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        })
    });
})

on select the following Controller function is going to be triggered:
public function filter(Request $request) {
    $portfolioItemByTagName = portfolioItem::where('tag', 'like', '%' . $request->type . '%')
    ->orWhere('tag', 'like', '%' . $request->technology . '%')
    ->orWhere('tag', 'like', '%' . $request->design . '%')
    ->orWhere('tag', 'like', '%' . $request->feature . '%')->get();

    return response()->json([$request->toArray()]);
}


Haven't you ever heard about AJAX?

Use Blade components, Livewire you may want to look into. (Your question is not a good fit for the site IMHO, but that's just some comment)

use ajax it good for starters.

Thank you for your answers. I updated the question with the solution. I do have an additional question. When rendering the page an php variable $portfolioItem has been used to generate two items, that are now displayed. If i were to update this variable, via the function filter will the regeneration occur again ? Is there an type of .refresh() function to the eloquent model ? What would the solution to this issue be ?

For laravel blade you may want to use axios. I wouldnt recommend clean ajax because of crsf tokens etc
